# find the maximum argument of a list of complex numbers

Tags: python

> question: The module cmath contains a function called polar that takes a complex number and returns a tuple containing that number's modulus and argument.  Import the module, and use this function to find the maximum argument of  (7+13i)<sup>n</sup> for values of n between 1 and 100.

I wrote:

```
import cmath
print(max([cmath.polar((7+13*1j)**n) for n in range(0,101)]))
```

which returns:

```
(8.371912492641356e+116, 0.8713455654785698)
```

the answer is 3.0434321161121605
I am aware that I have used the max function wrong in this case. I am unsure what I should write to get the value 3.0434321161121605. I would appreciate any help. thankyou.

Comment: You are sorting the entire tuple returned by `cmath.polar()` - basically, you are sorting by modulus, and only using the argument as a tie-breaker.  You need a `[1]` in there to extract the argument from the tuple.

Answer (score 1):

The question said to maximize the argument, which is the second element of the tuple. So extract that element of the result of `cmath.polar()`

```
print(max(cmath.polar((7+13j)**n)[1] for n in range(1,101)))
```

returns:

```
3.0434321161121605
```

Other notes:

You can just write `13j`, you don't need to multiply `13*1j`.

The range should start from `1`, not `0`.

Comment: The answer is just 3.0434321161121605 not (2.601979662211086e+37, 3.0434321161121605). How would I get this?

Comment: That's even easier. Just use `[1]` on the result of `cmath.polar()` to get the argument, and use that in the `max()` call.